# Hamiltonian form of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hamiltonian-path

I am quite new in this field and I was wondering what does exactly mean to write a PDE (in 2 or 3 dimensions) in an Hamiltonian form.
More in detail, is there any standard procedure to write a given PDE in its Hamiltonian form?